# Visualizing multiple embedding With Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, embedding

I would like to visualize my data based on multiple tensor variables, that is, based on different embedding variables. In other words what I need to do is the following:

I need to store the 100 dimensional vector (image feature/embeddings) into 5 different variables. Then I need to visualize my data based on the 5 different variables. That is, I need to visualize my data based on the first 20 features, and based on the second 20 features and so on...

While I was looking into the embedding visualization tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz, they say that we can add multiple embeddings. This is what I am looking for.

How to do this in tensorflow?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason it didn't work is because I was trying to divide the 100 dimensional embedding into 100 different variables. And that did not work. So when I divided my embeddings into 5 different parts, that is, dividing them into 5 different variables, it worked out. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

LOG_DIR = \
    'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/VariationalAutoEncoder/' \
    'Tensorflow-DeconvNet-Segmentation/Embeddings/features_images.ckpt'

feature_vectors = np.loadtxt('features.txt')
feature_vectors = feature_vectors[:5329]

print("feature_vectors_shape:",feature_vectors.shape)

sub_features = []
for i in range(20):
    features = tf.Variable(feature_vectors[:, 5 * i: 5 * (i + 1)], name=('features' + str(i)))
    sub_features.append(features)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, LOG_DIR)

    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    for i in range(20):
        embedding = config.embeddings.add()
        embedding.tensor_name = sub_features[i].name

        embedding.sprite.image_path = \
            'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/VariationalAutoEncoder/Tensorflow-DeconvNet-Segmentation/master.jpg'
        embedding.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([112, 112])

    # Saves a config file that TensorBoard will read during startup.
    projector.visualize_embeddings(tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR), config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should run showing two different embeddings. Notice you need to go to the "Projector" tab. Sometimes it doesn't open automatically.

```
log_dir='./logs'
embeddings=np.random.randint(1,100,(400,6))
labels=[1,2,3,4]*100


with open(f'{log_dir}/metadata.tsv', "w") as file: 
    for label in labels:
        file.write(f'{label}\n')

with open(f'{log_dir}/metadata2.tsv', "w") as file: 
    for label in labels:
        file.write(f'{label}\n')




os.makedirs(log_dir,exist_ok=True)


embeddings1=tf.Variable(embeddings,name='var1')
embeddings2=tf.Variable(embeddings,name='var2')

checkpoint=tf.train.Checkpoint(var1=embeddings1,var2=embeddings2)
checkpoint.save(log_dir+'/var.ckpt')




config=projector.ProjectorConfig()
emb1=config.embeddings.add()
emb1.tensor_name='var1'+'/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE'
emb1.metadata_path='metadata.tsv'

emb2=config.embeddings.add()
emb2.tensor_name='var2'+'/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE'
emb2.metadata_path='metadata2.tsv'

projector.visualize_embeddings(log_dir, config)

%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir ./logs/
```